# Need help building an Expression

Tags: microsoft-access

Need to know how to build an expression from this query:Create a new column to display High Priority for all loans that have an InterestRate of 7.5% or more, and Low Priority otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for MS Access in particular but a generic version of the query might be

```
alter table <table_name> add <column_name> varchar2(30)

update <table_name> set <column_name> = case when <interest_rate> >= 7.5 then 'HIGH PRIORITY' else 'LOW PRIORITY'
```